# upload multiple file in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I want to Upload multiple files in my project Symfony 2 But there was a error

When you try to add more than one file out to me this error

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbzTB.png)

code entity:

```
    <?php

namespace CrudBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Actualite
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CrudBundle\Entity\ActualiteRepository")
 */
class Actualite
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomactualite", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nomactualite;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contenuactualite", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $contenuactualite;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Matche", mappedBy="actualites")
     */
    private $matches;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Equipe", inversedBy="actualite")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_stade",referencedColumnName="id") 
     */
    private $equipe;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Equipe", mappedBy="actualites")
     */
    private $equipe1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

     /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomactualite
     *
     * @param string $nomactualite
     * @return Actualite
     */

    public function setNomactualite($nomactualite)
    {
        $this->nomactualite = $nomactualite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomactualite
     *
     * @return string 
     */

    public function getNomactualite()
    {
        return $this->nomactualite;
    }

    /**
     * Set contenuactualite
     *
     * @param string $contenuactualite
     * @return Actualite
     */
    public function setContenuactualite($contenuactualite)
    {
        $this->contenuactualite = $contenuactualite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contenuactualite
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContenuactualite()
    {
        return $this->contenuactualite;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->matches = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add matches
     *
     * @param \CrudBundle\Entity\Matche $matches
     * @return Actualite
     */
    public function addMatch(\CrudBundle\Entity\Matche $matches)
    {
        $this->matches[] = $matches;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove matches
     *
     * @param \CrudBundle\Entity\Matche $matches
     */
    public function removeMatch(\CrudBundle\Entity\Matche $matches)
    {
        $this->matches->removeElement($matches);
    }

    /**
     * Get matches
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMatches()
    {
        return $this->matches;
    }


    /**
     * Set equipe
     *
     * @param \CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe $equipe
     * @return Actualite
     */
    public function setEquipe(\CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe $equipe = null)
    {
        $this->equipe = $equipe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get equipe
     *
     * @return \CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe 
     */
    public function getEquipe()
    {
        return $this->equipe;
    }

    /**
     * Add equipe1
     *
     * @param \CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe $equipe1
     * @return Actualite
     */
    public function addEquipe1(\CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe $equipe1)
    {
        $this->equipe1[] = $equipe1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove equipe1
     *
     * @param \CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe $equipe1
     */
    public function removeEquipe1(\CrudBundle\Entity\Equipe $equipe1)
    {
        $this->equipe1->removeElement($equipe1);
    }

    /**
     * Get equipe1
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getEquipe1()
    {
        return $this->equipe1;
    }

    /**
 * @ORM\PreFlush()
 */


     public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/Actualite';
    }


    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
        public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }


    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;
}


    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

}
```

code Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace CrudBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ActualiteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nomactualite','text')
            ->add('contenuactualite', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')))
           ->add('file', new FilesType(), array(
                'label'    =>    'Photos',
                'required' =>    true,
                'attr'     =>    array(
                'accept'  =>  'article/*', )
                ))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CrudBundle\Entity\Actualite'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'crudbundle_actualite';
    }
}
```

code form:

```
    <?php

namespace CrudBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ActualiteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nomactualite','text')
            ->add('contenuactualite', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')))
           ->add('file', new FilesType(), array(
                'label'    =>    'Photos',
                'required' =>    true,
                'attr'     =>    array(
                'accept'  =>  'article/*', )
                ))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CrudBundle\Entity\Actualite'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'crudbundle_actualite';
    }
}
```

code FileType:

```
    <?php

    namespace CrudBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    /**
    * Class FilesType
    */
    class FilesType extends FileType
    {
        public function buildView(FormView $view, \Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);
            $view->vars['full_name'] .= '[]';
            $view->vars['attr']['multiple'] = 'multiple';
        }

        /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
            $resolver->setDefaults(
                array(
                    'data_class' => null,
                )
            );
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'files';
        }
    }
?>
```

Waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that this method in your \CrudBundle\Entity\Actualite class :

```
/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}
```

Is getting an array (of files?) instead of a single file.

You have modified (extended) `FileType` to work with multiple files, but you did not modify your `Actualite` class accordingly to accept them.

Comment: how to modify Actualite class !?

Comment: Modify it to accept an array and do whatever you want with those multiple files. After all, you did modify the FileType to accept multiple files. Now you have to deal with them.

Comment: Can you work on the modification work of this class,I did not understand you

Comment: A little effort from your side would also be very appreciated!

Comment: /**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
} , in this function I will change $file to $array !!! and in class fileType Where will the change! Because when I choose the files are selected more than one file at a normal pressure but in addition there is an error